# Find what table a specific index belongs to

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I have the name of an index, what query can I use to find what table the index belongs to?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = '...'
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
Select object_Name(Id) IndexName,
  object_name(parent_Obj) Tablename
From SysObjects
Where Type In ('K', 'F')
order By object_name(parent_Obj), 
         object_Name(Id)
```

Comment: @Evildonald I think you did not have the right database in use.

Comment: Maybe that was it.  This was so long ago I can't even remember :D

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach than Lukasz since my index wasn't of type k or f.

```
Select object_Name(Id) IndexName,
object_name(parent_Obj) Tablename
From SysObjects
where object_name(id) like 'MyIndexName'
order By object_name(parent_Obj), 
         object_Name(Id)
```